# How to capture HTTP throughput in BlackBerry?

Tags: http, blackberry, throughput

Please help me to findout the HTTP throughput and HTTP latency in the BB programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get timestamps at various points in your code, then use those values to calculate timings.  For example:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
long opened = System.currentTimeMillis();
String body = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(connection.openInputStream()));
long done = System.currentTimeMillis();

long bytes = body.length();
float durationSeconds = (float)(done - opened) / 1000.0f;
float bytesPerSecond = bytes / durationSeconds;

System.out.println("Latency: " + (opened - start) + " ms");
System.out.println("Bandwidth: " + bytesPerSecond + " bytes per second");
```